# tcltk block input while processing in r

Tags: r, tk-toolkit

[RGTK2 block user input while processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061986/rgtk2-block-user-input-while-processing) its explain how to block user input using RGTK2 but I dont know how to add that code to my GUI code, im using tcltk. What I want same like in [RGTK2 block user input while processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061986/rgtk2-block-user-input-while-processing) but using tcltk2

I use this code to run button "filter cluster" and the command function is filter (function to do something)

```
tkpack(tkbutton(f4, text='Filter Cluster', command=filter), side='left',padx= 5, pady = 20)
```

Answer (score 1):

In [`tcltk`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/tcltk/tcl), you would use `tkgrab.set` on a non-responsive window and `tkfocus` on a window that has a binding on the `<Key>` event that prevents further processing. An inconspicuous `tkframe` is great for that sort of thing — set it to size 1×1, but ensure it is on the screen — as it has no default behaviour to get in the way. (You'll also want to make a bunch of cosmetic changes, such as marking the widgets as disabled and setting the cursor to `watch`.) In 8.6, there's `tk busy` (call with `tcl("tk","busy",…)` since the Tcl `tk` command appears to not have a convenient mapping) which makes this all much easier (though I don't know if/how that's mapped into R). The simplest way to release a grabbed window is to destroy it, but you can also `tkgrab.release`.

***Do not use a global grab.*** They're easy to get wrong and can cause you a lot of grief. (If you insist, you're strongly recommended to make mouse activity cancel it and to *test very thoroughly*. Locking up your display is not a pleasant experience!) The default local grabs are less of a problem, since you can switch to another program and kill off a stuck app if necessary.

The full documentation for Tk (and Tcl) is [online](http://www.tcl.tk/man/); pick the version of the docs for the version of the library that you're using, probably 8.5, hopefully 8.6 ('cos it has some nice extras) and possibly 8.4 (old skool!) As the R documentation for `tcltk` says, you can invoke anything in Tcl or Tk through `tcl(…)`, passing in the words of the command name and arguments as many strings… (Tcl is a naturally var-args language and uses that extensively.) The limited scope of the default convenience mapping should not hinder you substantively.

---

### General advice, not so closely related to your question

Most Tk programmers try to write their code to not lock users out that way if possible. You get a better user experience if you can keep the GUI responsive and instead just temporarily disable (via the `state` option on most reactive widgets) the parts that would otherwise trigger reentrancy problems for the duration. (The long-running processing might be also event-driven, or put in another thread, or even delegated to a sub-process. Just remember, Tk GUIs are *strictly* single threaded — the implementation assumes this very deeply, though it's possible to have wholly independent apps in different threads, if rather hairy to get working right — so you've got to come back to the GUI thread to update anything in the GUI.)